# How to get rid of return keyword error in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python.
I have written the below code to test a method in python.
However, the return line throws an error, not sure as to why. 
Below is the code and the error.

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, first ,last,email ,pay):
     self.first = first
     self.last = last
     self.email = email
     self.pay = pay

     def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first. self.last)


emp1 = Employee("COREY","Schafer","COREY.Schafer@gmail.com",60000)
emp2 = Employee("rahul","ravi","rahul.ravi@emc.com","70000")

print(emp1.email)
print(emp2.email)

#print('{} {}'.format(emp1.first, emp1.last))

print(emp1.fullname())
```

Error:

```
    return '{} {}'.__format__(self.first. self.last)
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Your indent is not ok, python is sensitive to correct indent.

Comment: Tab in `return '{} {}'.__format__(self.first. self.last)` and all your other code that you wish to be within the function

Comment: Your code is not correctly indented, you should indent the line `return '{} {}'.format(self.first. self.last)` 4 spaces with respect to the preceding line.

Comment: `def fullname` should have its indentation reduced so it is not inside `__init__`. Then its `return` statement should be indented so it is inside `fullname`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, first ,last,email ,pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = email
        self.pay = pay
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first. self.last)
```

In your given code, indentation is problematic.

Comment: fixed it. this should do.

Answer (score 0):

Python is **very** sensitive to indentation. A block of code should have exactly 4 spaces for every level of indent.

So, this is wrong:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, first ,last,email ,pay):
     self.first = first
     self.last = last
     self.email = email
     self.pay = pay

     def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first. self.last)
```

This is OK:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first, last, email, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = email
        self.pay = pay

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)
```

EDIT: You had also an error in return.

Comment: It's not the 1-space, 4-space difference that's causing the actual error. You can write code 1-space indentation and it will work, it's just not very clear.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but 4-space is technically correct *and* the style is also good. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a good lesson on indentation. I got another error with calling the method with the instance emp1, emp2.

Comment: code goes like this emp1.fullname() , emp1.(no function listed)

Comment: @RahulRao If an answer has solved the question you asked about, you should accept it. You can ask other questions as their own questions.

Comment: @RahulRao `return '{} {}'.format(self.first. self.last)` should be `return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)` (note the comma after `first` instead of the dot).
Also, FYI, indentation does not need to be consistent for different pieces of code as long as the same indentantion is kept for the same level.